# Properly setting up angular 7 with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use ng-bootstrap in my project.
I searched the net and found that I need to install bootstrap 4 and ng-bootstrap.
I initialized a brand new project and installed:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",

"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"
```

I was then talled to do on my app.module.ts

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

The `.forRoot()` method is unknown and I get the error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(13,23): error TS2339: Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'.

I work with Angular 7.X.

Comment: As per ngb-bootstrap document no need to write `.forRoot()`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 5):

Remove `.forRoot(),` so that your imports will look like this:

```
imports: [
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
],
```